# Make invalid XAML prevent compilation

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

The compiler is very generous when it comes to errors in XAML code. For instance misspelled Bindings do not even throw an error at runtime.

Can I change the settings to make the compiler more strict when it comes to XAML? I want to see these errors at design time.

Comment: I've seen Xamarin provide support for this but not sure if it could be ported to WPF or Windows Store apps.  Here is the link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Answer (score 2):

> Can I change the settings to make the compiler more strict when it comes to XAML?

No, because the binding paths are actually resolved at *runtime* using reflection.

The Universal Windows Platform (UWP) introduced the concept of compiled bindings using the `{x:Bind}` syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

But in WPF there is no such thing and the compiler doesn't even evaluate the binding paths for you. As mentioned these are resolved at runtime.

There are some things you can do to be able to *trace* binding errors at runtime though. Please refer to the following link for more information about this: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work reliably using ordinary bindings. Even if you use jetbrains build tools to detect binding errors, you can never be certain that the binding might change at runtime on some level and break every binding subsequently.